# How to put a command in a SH file

Tags: bash, file, terminal, command

I'm using wine to open a game and to open the game I must enter the following command in the terminal

```
cd "/home/brandon/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/League of Legends/RADS/system"
```

Then I enter this below

```
WINEDEBUG=+ntdll wine "rads_user_kernel.exe" run lol_launcher $(ls ../projects/lol_launcher/releases/) LoLLauncher.exe
```

and then the game normally loads.

Is it possible to put the 1st command and the 2nd command together in an .sh file so I just double click it and everything will be automatic?

Comment: Probably, though I'm not sure of all the details.  Please clarify which version of Linux you are using, as that might affect how you do things.  The first thing to try is to create a file with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and the other two lines after that.  Make it executable (`chmod +x gamefile.sh`), and then try clicking on `gamefile.sh`.  If that doesn't work, then you can still just type `gamefile.sh` at the command line (foregoing the clicking) to run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/brandon/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/League of Legends/RADS/system"
WINEDEBUG=+ntdll wine "rads_user_kernel.exe" run lol_launcher $(ls ../projects/lol_launcher/releases/) LoLLauncher.exe
```

If I understand your problem correctly, this should run the two commands through the script.

You also will have to do

```
chmod u+x name_of_script
```

before you can run it.